# What mind mapping software is scalable to thousands of nodes?

Tags: windows, mind-mapping, scalability

I've been using XMind for about 3 years. I write down a lot of information in it, which causes the file to become quite large. After a while (>1000 nodes) everything becomes slow - loading, saving, browsing the tree. At some point XMind has an "out of memory" problem, and I must create a new file, and juggle between them. That is annoying.

Is there any scalable mind mapping software out there? Preferably free, but commercial is fine.

Comment: Why the downvotes? (the Q is rather legit IMO.)

Comment: Without knowing more about your context and your problem, is smelling to me more like a wrong focused problem more than a technical gap.

Comment: @uprego, please explain.

Comment: I don't see why you, a person, assuming you are not representing a corporation wanting to attack a big problem with a monolithic solution, would have a problem so big that needs a model bigger than a thousand entities. Here is important for you to understand the significance of the words **model** and **entity** applied to a context of computer science.

Comment: @uprego, I write about 10 topics each day - what I need to do and what I've done, kind of a diary with hyperlinks to files. It becomes about 20*12*10 = 2400 topics per year. I am not using it for modelling software if that is what you are implying.

Comment: Don't mind map them, use [treeline](http://treeline.bellz.org/)

Comment: Those kind of programs are not graph friendly and prompt you to organize your tasks with a tree. But in the corner case I would bet that is better for you to fork treeline or similar software to support graphs rather than using mind mapping software for the daily schedule and of course the past journal.

Comment: @Shiki In regards to your first comment, product recommendation requests are not "legit", they are off-topic according to the [site policy](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Moses, according to http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software/5373#5373, my question fits the format of "I have problem-x that I don't know how to solve. I've already tried X, Y, Z, but those programs don't work because this or that. How do I do this?" , where x = "Need to write down thousand of nodes", X = "XMind" and this or that = "everything becomes slow". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) has a user who has successfully gone up to [22,000 nodes](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Asked_questions#What_is_the_largest_size_mindmap_I_can_edit_with_FreeMind.3F) (with some slowdown, but still useable) on a rather old computer with 2GB of RAM.

[image]